# Identifying special solutions to ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I came across this ODE:

> $ y' = 2(\frac{y}{x}) + 1 $

I managed to solve it absolutely fine, recognising it was a Homogenous first-order ODE, using the substitution $v = y/x$ etc.

My answer was -

> $ y = Ax^2 - x $
>   where $A = \pm e^c $

See, that was where my set of solutions thwarted, however $ y = -x $ is considered a 'special solution'.

How would I go about identifying this, because $ \pm e^c \ne 0$ so I am struggling to figure it out on my own.

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: I see no need for such a substitution, as it's already a linear DE. Note that the construction of $A$ isn't necessarily important: $A$ can be any constant and $y$ will still solve the DE. So, $A = 0$ isn't a problem.

Comment: @Kaynex I see, I see. So the fact that e^c restricts A to not equal 0, it means I need to take into A = 0 as this constant is allowed to take any value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are solving the equation you need to be careful of situations like $\frac{1}{v+1}$. What happens when $y = -x$?

Comment: Okay, 1/v+1 becomes x/(y+x) so when y = -x you are dividing by 0. What implication does this fact have on the special solution existence? Thank you

Comment: In your substitution you went from $xv^\prime = v + 1$ to $\int \frac{dv}{v+1} = \int \frac{dx}{x}$. This is not kosher when $v = -1$. When $v = -1$, you get $\frac{y}{x} = -1$ or $y = -x$, which is your missing solution.

Answer (score 0):

$$y'-\frac{2}{x}y=1\implies\mu=e^{-2\operatorname{ln}x+C}=C_1x^{-2}$$

$$(y\mu)'=C_1x^{-2}\implies y=\frac{1}{\mu}(-C_1x^{-1}+C_2)=-x+C_3x^2$$

$C_3=\frac{C_2}{C_1}$

$C_2 \in \mathbb{R}$

$C_1=e^C$

$C\in\mathbb{R}$

$C_1\neq0$ but $C_2$ is any number so  $C_3$ can be $0$